Can't find Assembly for GetConsoleOrTerminalWindow
I'm trying to implement an MSAL Interactive scenario login in a desktop Windows application. The sample code includes .WithParentActivityOrWindow(GetConsoleOrTerminalWindow) when building the Public Client Application.
I don't have GetConsoleOrTerminalWindow available to me and I can't find the package or assembly to reference to access it. It's obviously an IntPtr handle to the relevant window, but it just says it's not declared.
Am I missing something obvious?

Could you edit your question and add more details on your requirement like your complete code, error if any?

Hi @Thoth2020 Any update?

The sample code that you are referring from this MS Document uses authentication broker component like Web Account Manager(WAM) for public client scenarios.
In my case, I registered one application and added below redirect URI in Mobile & Desktop applications platform, along with enabling public client flows option:
ms-appx-web://microsoft.aad.brokerplugin/appIdhere


Now, I created one .NET 6.0 console app and installed Microsoft.Identity.Client & Microsoft.Identity.Client.Broker packages in it like this:

To generate access token using interactive flow in this application, I used below sample code in it:
Program.cs:
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client.Broker;

class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };
        var tenantId = "yourtenantIDhere";
        var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";

        var brokerOptions = new BrokerOptions(BrokerOptions.OperatingSystems.Windows)
        {
            Title = "My Awesome Application"
        };

        IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create("yourappIDhere")
            .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
            .WithAuthority(authority)
            .WithParentActivityOrWindow(() => GetConsoleWindow())
            .WithBroker(brokerOptions)
            .Build();

        AuthenticationResult result = null;

        try
        {
            IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
            IAccount existingAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

            if (existingAccount != null)
            {
                result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, existingAccount).ExecuteAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No accounts found in the cache.");
            }

            if (result == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Acquiring token interactively...");
                result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
            result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            return;
        }

        if (result != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Access Token:");
            Console.WriteLine(result.AccessToken);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to acquire token.");
        }
    }
}

Response:

Access token:

When I decoded the above access token in jwt.ms, I got aud and scp claim values like this:

